# Seeing history since a given commit with all commit messages from merged branches too

Tags: git

Using commands such as

```
git log hash..hash --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph
```

includes merges of branches in it's output, but not the commit messages performed on the branches 'merged from'. Is there any way to include also the commit messages for the commits made on the branches 'merged from' before they were merged in, to get a more full description of all changes actually affecting the history between the two hashes?

Motivation: the branches merged from, may have had commit messages on them, for commits that happened before the first hash (of the log command above). It's useful to have the descriptions of those commits, to better understand the full history, rather than only knowing that 'something was merged'.

This can greatly help scan what really happened between two hashes, without reading every changed line of code. And it's useful for release documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: i dont think this would be a well-defined operation if the merged-in branches do not fork from your branch after your starting hash. the merge commit will always be in the line between starting-hash and ending-hash, its predecessors will not.

Comment: "but not the commit messages performed on the branches 'merged from'" In a simple test, they do show up for me. Can you give commands to create a simple test git repo where it fails for you?

Comment: @hvd, does it mean that when I see 'merged x into y' on the output, but no lines about what was committed into x, then it simply means no commits were made on x that introduce any real change to y?

Comment: @matt There are various things it could mean. A very simple alternate possibility is that the merge commit you're looking at isn't actually a merge commit, but a regular commit that happens to have "Merge" in the commit message (which is normal after `git merge --squash`). That's why it would be helpful to have some real data.

Comment: A different way to ask this is 'how can one tell if a merge commit introduced more changes than those already encompassed in the log output for the given range'. I will add an example after I create it as I can't post my real history. Sorry.